# Remove array value quote

Tags: php

I am trying to remove quote from my array value staring and ending.I used str_replace but not work.Actually I cant understand.

my code

```
foreach ($freq as $index =>  $chartData) {
    $data = implode (',', $chartData);
    $chartArray  [] = array (
        "name" => $index,
        "data" => $data
    );

}

return json_encode($chartArray);
```

It returns

```
 series:[{"name":"failed","data":"0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"}]
```

But I need look like

```
 series:[{"name":"failed","data":0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}]
```

Comment: The way you want it to look makes no sense, and isn't valid JSON. Perhaps you want `[{"name":"failed","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]` instead, where `data` is an *array* of numeric values?

Comment: If you want `data` to be an array of integers it should be assigned as an array.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're *actually* looking for is something like this:

```
series:[{"name":"failed","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

Just remove the `implode` line, and pass the `$chartData` array directly to `json_encode`:

```
foreach ($freq as $index =>  $chartData) {
    $chartArray  [] = array (
        "name" => $index,
        "data" => $chartData
    );

}

return json_encode($chartArray);
```